# SU(2,$\Bbb C$) homeomorphic to $S^3$

Tags: general-topology

Good day,

I understand how to show that for a $M= $$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a & b \\
        c & d \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$ \in$ SU(2,$\Bbb C$), $M=$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a & b \\
        -\bar b & \bar a \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$ and that $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$. However, I don't understand why the set $A=\{ (a,b) \in \Bbb C^2 | |a|^2+|b|^2=1 \}$ is homeomorphic to the set $(a,b)\in S^3 $; since $\Bbb C^n$ maps bijectively to $\Bbb R^{2n}$, shouldn't $A$ be homeomorphic to $(a,b) \in S^4$ instead?

Best wishes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention is that $S^n$ is the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. (With dimension $n$) Here you work in $\mathbb{R}^4$ so the sphere you're interested in is $S^3$.